# How to use geometry of vector tile layer in mapbox to make intersections with Turf.js?

Tags: reactjs, geometry, intersection, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I am using Mapbox-gl in React.

I am trying to make an intersection between a polygon selected and a complete layer

```
 map.on('click', 'buildings', function(e) {
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
      // getting the main polygon
      const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {layers:['buildings']);
      // getting the features of layer with which to make intersection 
      const featurestoTest = map.queryRenderedFeatures({layers: ['floodplains_from_2016']});

      let building = undefined;
      let fll = undefined;
      features.forEach( feat => {
          building = turf.polygon(feat.geometry);
          featurestoTest.forEach( (feature) => {
            fll = turf.polygon(feature.geometry);
            // until here there is no error, but one it tries to intersect throws error  
            const featureIntersect = turf.intersect(fll, building);
          })
        }
      });
    });
```

The error thrown is

> Error: coordinates must only contain numbers

The geometry types returned by MAPBOX are like this:

```
type: "Polygon"
coordinates: Array(1)
0: Array(25)
   0: (2) [-77.02939443290234, 38.89539175681929]
   1: (2) [-77.02935017645359, 38.89536461871285]
   ...
```

So I wonder how should be constructed the polygons to use turf.intersection after clicked a polygon in Mapbox.js

Answer (score 1):

The turf.polygon() method takes an array of coordinates as an argument. You should use `feat.geometry.coordinates` instead of only `feat.geometry`